# Virtual functions along with inheritance

Tags: c++

Am learning CPP and in the below code snippet, I am expecting 40 as the answer, but getting 30. Can anyone please help to identify what am I doing wrong.

The program may not make sense, but its just for learning.

```
class Shape {

protected:
    int shape = 10;
public:

    int get() {
        return shape;
    }
    virtual void process() {
        shape = 30;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {

public:
    void process() {
        shape = 40;
    }

};


class Object : Shape {

    Shape m_sh;
public:
    Object(Shape &sh) {
        m_sh = sh;
        m_sh.process();
    }

    int getShape() {
        return m_sh.get();
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Rectangle rect;
    Object obj1 = Object(rect);

    std::cout << obj1.getShape() << std::endl; // am expecting 40, but getting 30.

}
```

Comment: You're a victim of _object slicing_, lookup that. Use a pointer or reference to avoid that.

Comment: @TheDude but I am using a reference ( Shape &sh ). Where exactly is the object slicing hapenning?

Comment: You store it in a `Shape m_sh`, which is not a reference.

Comment: @infoclogged  *Where exactly is the object slicing hapenning?* -- `m_sh = sh;`

Comment: In addition to what was already said: your design seems off. Your Object _is_ a shape, and, simultaneously _has_ a shape. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @infoclogged "_If any moderator wants to delete this, its fine with me_" You can delete it yourself, if you want to..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - yes, you are right . Object: Shape is unnecessary. I have deleted the comment about deletion, since it has been already taken care.